# Button click to wait for button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I have two buttons: Btn1 `<input type="button" class="buttons" value="Test">`
and Btn2 `<input type="button" class="buttons" value="Test2">`. I want to be able to click on Btn1 and Btn1 waits for the second button to be pressed and if the second button (Btn2) is pressed the output is Test Test2 is this possible?
I know how to do the button clicks of course but I can't find a solution for the first button to wait for the second one

Comment: What have you tried so far? Click first btn, mark flag, click btn2, do output if flag is marked

Comment: What do you mean by "wait"? You can disable button 1 when click so that you are able to click only in button 2.

Comment: what have you tried so far,, if you show us our code we might help further... also this can be as simple as disabling the first button unless the second is clicked.. once its clicked then enable it..

Comment: You can add a class to the first button with a jquery onclick function. For example: `$(this).addClass("clicked");` And check if that class is attached to the first button, when it is, output the data when the second button is clicked.

Comment: 1. OnButton1 click -> Set a variable to true 2. onButton2 click if variable is true -> "Test Test2" if variable is false -> "Test2"

Comment: @aRsen49 thanks that helped a lot pretty simple but didn't came to my mind

Comment: @ImReallyHungryYouKnow, I posted it as an answer. If it helped you, I would appreciate it if you could mark it as the answer! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-
If you are using Input Buttons like this:-

```
<input type="button" id="button1" class="buttons" value="Test" />
<input type="button" id="button2" class="buttons" value="Test2" />
<textarea name="test" id="test" rows="8" cols="80" readonly></textarea>
```

Then use this script:-

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var flag1 = false;
    var result;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[ID$='button1']").click(function () {
            flag1 = true;
            alert("you clicked button 'Test', Click another button for result");
        });
        $("input[ID$='button2']").click(function () {
            if (flag1 == true) {
                //flag1 = false;
                if (result)
                    result = result + " " + $("input[ID$='button1']").val() + " " + $("input[ID$='button2']").val();
                else
                    result = $("input[ID$='button1']").val() + " " + $("input[ID$='button2']").val();
                // alert(result);
                document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = result;
            }
            else {
                //alert("Please click button 'Test' first");
                if (result)
                    result = result + " " + $("input[ID$='button2']").val();
                else
                    result = $("input[ID$='button2']").val();
                document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = result;
            }
        });
        window.onload = function () {
            if (flag1 == true) {
                //flag1 = false;
                if (result)
                    result = result + " " + $("input[ID$='button1']").val() + " " + $("input[ID$='button2']").val();
                else
                    result = $("input[ID$='button1']").val() + " " + $("input[ID$='button2']").val();
                //alert(result);
                document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = result;
            }
        };
    });
</script>
```

If you are using buttons like this:-

```
<button id="btntest1" class="buttons">Test</button>
<button id="btntest2" class="buttons">Test2</button>
<textarea name="test" id="test" rows="8" cols="80" readonly></textarea>
```

Then use this script:-

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button[ID$='btntest1']").click(function () {
            flag1 = true;
            alert("you clicked button 'Test', Click another button for result");
        });
        $("button[ID$='btntest2']").click(function () {
            if (flag1 == true) {
                //flag1 = false;
                if (result)
                    result = result + " " + $("button[ID$='btntest1']").html() + " " + $("button[ID$='btntest2']").html();
                else
                    result = $("button[ID$='btntest1']").html() + " " + $("button[ID$='btntest2']").html();
                //alert(result);
                document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = result;
            }
            else {
                //alert("Please click button 'Test' first");
                if (result)
                    result = result + " " + $("button[ID$='btntest2']").html();
                else
                    result = $("button[ID$='btntest2']").html();
                document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = result;                    
            }
        });
    });
    window.onload = function () {
        if (flag1 == true) {
            //flag1 = false;
            if (result)
                result = result + " " + $("button[ID$='btntest1']").html() + " " + $("button[ID$='btntest2']").html();
            else
                result = $("button[ID$='btntest1']").html() + " " + $("button[ID$='btntest2']").html();
            //alert(result);
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = result;
        }
    };
</script>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It's cool. In that way you don't have to disable the button as my approach, but you have to set flag to false when button2 is clicked.

Comment: @Ansari thank you but that <button> script isn't working at all

Comment: @ImReallyHungryYouKnow can copy my code properly and try again and delete all your comment above it is to lengthy conversation happening here

Answer (score 0):

depends on your needs.

1- Show button 1 enable
2- Show button 2 disable
3- onclick button 1 : 
    3.1 : set flags to btn1_clicked = true; and othe var you need 
    3.2 : Enable button 2
4 onclick button 2 do your output

It's just a global thinking, you can adapt .

Comment: Can you reformat it to more readable look.. I am not able to format it as I am not able to understand few things over there

Answer (score 0):

So, with the idea of my comment you can do this :

```js
btn1 = document.getElementById('btn-1');
btn2 = document.getElementById('btn-2');

btn1.addEventListener('click', function(){
  btn2.removeAttribute('disabled');
  btn1.disabled = 'disabled';
});

btn2.addEventListener('click', function(){
  btn1.removeAttribute('disabled');
  btn2.disabled = 'disabled';
  alert(btn2.value);
});
```

```html
<input id="btn-1" type="button" class="buttons" value="Test">
<input id="btn-2" type="button" class="buttons" value="Test 2" disabled>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comment...

1. OnButton1Click -> Set a flag to true
2. OnButton2Click -> If Variable is true -> "Test Test2" if variable is false -> "Test2"

I created a quick example all vanilla JS.

[JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/naxegonexo/edit?html,js,output)